# Using a list to generate dataframes in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, syntax

I have four dataframes df_may, df_jun, df_jul, df_aug.
Although I can write them to individual csv files manually with 4 lines of code, but I want to to this in a for loop.

This is what I tried, with a SytnaxError

```
months = ['may','jun','jul','aug']
for i in months:
       df_{}.format(i).to_csv('raw_master_{}'.format(i))
```

Also, can I extract the list 'months' somehow using existing dataframes in my notebook?

Comment: Why don't you use a dict with key being the name with which you want to write the csv and value being the actual dataframe and then loop over the keys of dictionary and write each dataframe with its respective name coming from the key of dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to associate the variable with the month:

```
month_dfs = {'may': df_may, 'jun': df_jun, 'jul': df_jul, 'aug': df_aug}
for month, df in month_dfs.items():
    df.to_csv(f'raw_master_{month}')
```

If you **REALLY** want to do this with matching the variable name, then you can use the `locals` function, but I don't recommend this. The code is really brittle and hard to understand and code analyzers/ linters won't be able to catch errors for you.

```
for month in months:
    locals()[f'df_{month}'].to_csv(f'raw_master_{month}')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, can I extract the list 'months' somehow using existing dataframes in my notebook?

You will need to specify what notebook you are referring to here, or what the data contains, otherwise it's hard to answer. If you can't get the month string directly from your DataFrames you can use zip().

```
for month, data in zip(['may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug'], [df_may, df_jun, df_jul, df_aug]):
       data.to_csv(f'raw_master_{month}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dinamically change a variable like you were trying to do with the `df_{}`. You can put all the dataframes in a list and iterate over it zipping it together with the list containing the months.

```py
months = ['may','jun','jul','aug']
df_list = [df_may, df_jun,df_jul,df_aug]
for df, month in zip(df_list, months) :
       df.to_csv(f'raw_master_{month}')
```

If you want to use the variables in a dynamic way, you could eventually use `globals() [f"df_{month}" ]`  or `locals()` or `eval(f"df_{month}")` in your code in place of `df_{}`